# RethinkDB: .get() with just part of the uuid?

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

Let's say this is the uuid of one of my documents in RethinkDB: `594a64ab-b78b-4838-a79f-318020a352a9`

Normally, to retrieve the document, I do:

`r.db("databasename").table("tablename").get('594a64ab-b78b-4838-a79f-318020a352a9')`

Is there some way I can achieve the same thing with only some prefixing portion of the uuid? e.g. I want to do this:

`r.db("databasename").table("tablename").getByPrefix('594a64ab-b78b')`

Is this possible?

Comment: @kureikain's solution will work, but why will you have only part of the UUID at the time of making the query?

Comment: @dalanmiller I want to use the uuid as a URL parameter, but not the entire uuid as it is really long. In a SQL world I would just do an autoincremented integer but of course rethink is not exactly optimized for that type of behaviour. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution, including all the steps:

**1/ Create test table**

```
r.table('foo').insert([
  {foo: 1},
  {foo: 2},
  {foo: 3},
  {foo: 4},
  {foo: 5}
])
```

**2/ List table content**

```
r.table('foo')
```

Output:

```
[
  {"foo":4,"id":"3c6873af-0dfc-41d3-99ad-894bab981635"},
  {"foo":1,"id":"302baaa5-1443-408c-bb58-7970e71129ac"},
  {"foo":2,"id":"ca5ff9c2-8079-4a19-9cfc-4e7b0a834555"},
  {"foo":5,"id":"aabb6c38-710a-444c-a4ae-b8ee14b5e802"},
  {"foo":3,"id":"4fc2e6e8-9434-4fa9-831b-4208bc82fd35"}
]
```

**3/ Create secondary index**

```
r.table('foo').indexCreate('id_prefix', function(d){
  return d('id').slice(0, 13)
})
```

**4/ List index content**

```
r.table('foo').distinct({index:'id_prefix'})
```

Output:

```
["302baaa5-1443","3c6873af-0dfc","4fc2e6e8-9434","aabb6c38-710a","ca5ff9c2-8079"]
```

**5/ Use the index to find the document(s) with prefix "4fc2e6e8-9434"**

```
r.table('foo').getAll("4fc2e6e8-9434", {index:'id_prefix'})
```

Output

```
[{"foo":3,"id":"4fc2e6e8-9434-4fa9-831b-4208bc82fd35"}]
```

This is a longer setup and solution, BUT, on a table of for example several millions docs, it can really make it faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can do use this but it is slow though:

```
r.db("databasename").table("tablename")
  .filter(r.row('id').match('^594a64ab-b78b')))
```